# Whatever Happened to Nearness Spaces?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, category-theory

I came across [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016660X7490021X) about Nearness Spaces. It seemed to be at the time (1970-80s) a promising approach to general topology via category theory. I have found no posts at all on stackexchange concerning Nearness Spaces. Has it hit a dead-end, been replaced by a better approach, simply forgotten, or called by a different name now?

Comment: Some [bibliographical references](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/h/Herrlich:Horst) for the author Horst Herrlich may be helpful to you.

Comment: Have you tried Wilipedia? Near sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the author's references and abstract suggest, nearness spaces are a slight generalization of [proximity spaces](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Proximity_space), an older concept.

There are a handful of [Questions at Math.SE about proximity spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=proximity+spaces+is%3Aquestion+%5Bgeneral-topology%5D).

Here are some "recent" research papers connected with nearness spaces:

- Khare, Mona and Surabhi Tiwari: "Approach Merotopological Spaces and their Completion", [Int. J. Math. and Math. Sciences (2010)](http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume2010/409804.pdf)
- Leseberg, D.: "Supernearness Spaces as a Tool for Studying Unification and Extensions", [Topology Atlas Invited Contributions 8 No. 3, 1–2 (2003)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312459.pdf)
- Yang, Zhanbo: "A New Proof on Embedding the Category of Proximity Spaces into the Category of Nearness Spaces", [Fundamenta Informaticae v.88 No. 1-2 (January 2008)](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2366266)
- ____ : "Pointwise convergence and Ascoli theorems for nearness spaces", [Applied General Topology Vol 10, No 1 (2009)](http://ojs.cc.upv.es/index.php/AGT/article/view/1787)

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for.